# Matlab access vectors from a multi-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a 4D matrix of size 300x200x3x20 where 300x200 is the size of one video frame, 3 is the number of channels (Red-Green-Blue channels) and 20 is the number of frames.

1. I want to extract all the color vectors from this matrix and store them in a 2D array of size 3x1,200,000 (300 x 200 x 20 = 1,200,000) where each row represents a component of the RGB color space and each column contain the RGB values of one pixel in the original matrix.
2. Besides, I want to carry out pixel-wise operations on this data such as extracting visual features but I cannot find a way to effectively access vectors along the third dimension.

How could I efficiently do these, possible without using loops?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "effectively access vectors along the third dimension"

Comment: By effective I mean not using loops. As for third dimension, it is where the pixel color vectors reside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code -

```
IN = your_4D_data;
OUT = reshape(permute(IN,[3 1 2 4]),3,numel(IN)/3);
```

Comment: Is there any difference between shiftdim(), as suggested by ben, and permute(), assuming the two could achieve the same thing?

Comment: SHIFTDIM is mainly used to "squeeze" dimensions if one of the them is 1. PERMUTE rearranges the dimensions of INPUT so that they are in the order specified by the vector order as the second argument. Official documentations on these might help you to get a better idea about them and why PERMUTE is what you need. So, they are two very different things.

Answer (score 1):

`help reshape` says:
B = reshape(A,m,n,p,...) or B = reshape(A,[m n p ...]) returns an n-dimensional array with the same elements as A but reshaped to have the size m-by-n-by-p-by-.... The product of the specified dimensions, m*n*p*..., must be the same as numel(A).

is this what you are looking for?

also, you can adress pixels like this: `Matrix(i,j,:,k)` which gives you the 3 colorchanels of pixel i,j in frame k.

Comment: Reshape() does not seem to work as it first traverses the matrix column-by-column, i.e. extract vectors from the second dimension while what I need is that it goes along the third dimension.

Comment: you can also use [`shiftdim`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/shiftdim.html) to work around that

Comment: I want to carry out the same operations to all RGB vectors in the third dimension of the matrix. There is no need to access each individual pixel.